# PHP: from string to array: argument => parametr

Tags: php, arrays

I have got strings like:

```
name="n e" content="12" icon="favicon.ico"
```

What is the best and quickest way to parse it as such array:

```
Array
(
    [name] => "n e"
    [content] => "12"
    [icon] => "favicon.ico"
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it, using `preg_match_all()` to get all the groups and `array_combine()` to form the final array:

```
if (preg_match_all('/(\w+)="([^"]*)"/', $str, $matches)) {
    return array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
} else {
    return array();
}
```

**Edit**

This alternative breaks when there are spaces in between the double quotes; otherwise it works as well:

```
parse_str(str_replace(array(' ', '"'), array('&', ''), $s), $a);
return $a;
```

Comment: @JonStirling Upon first sight it seemed to work, but as OP pointed out, it breaks when spaces are inside the double quoted strings :/ the `preg` method works of course :)

Comment: @Jack I maintain my +1 for putting it in there all the same :D